# How to have multiple sites using Apache2?

Tags: 13.04, apache2, virtualhost

I would like to have 2 sites on my development machine.

I edited /etc/hosts as follow

```
127.0.0.1       restaurant.local    www.restaurant.local
127.0.0.1   lrv4.local      www.lrv4.local
```

I created 2 new files /etc/apache2/sites-available/restaurant.local and ../lrv4.local

```
<VirtualHost restaurant.local:80>
    ServerName restaurant.local
    ServerAlias www.restaurant.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/restaurant/public
    <Directory /var/www/restaurant/public/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/restaurant.local-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost lrv4.local:80>
    ServerName lrv4.local
    ServerAlias www.lrv4.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/lrv4/public
    <Directory /var/www/lrv4/public/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/lrv4.local-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

these 2 files are relatively similar to one another.

I enabled these 2 sites using

```
sudo a2ensites restaurant.local
sudo a2ensites lrv4.local
```

I also check enabled sites using

```
ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
```

My problem is when I tried to access lrv4.local, I got the page belongs to restaurant.local, I tried to check the log file which I declared in VirtualHost config file above, all logs are logged into /var/log/apache2/restaurant.local-access.log, nothing are logged into /var/log/apache2/lrv4.local-access.log.

Please help.

Comment: What caught my eye in your configuration is that you use the server name in the VirtualHost directive. So far I've only seen the * catchall (`<VirtualHost *:80>`) or an IP address (`<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>`) in that place, but never something like `<VirtualHost restaurant.local:80>`. I clearly can't rule out that this is a perfectly fine way to use VirtualHost that I just haven't come across yet. But on the other hand, if it actually makes Apache choke on your virtual host definitions, it might explain your problem.

Comment: That's useful for me, I will tried what you suggested, thanks.

Comment: I solved my problem, it is just as you said, thanks.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck, you could add your comment as an answer and since your suggestion was correct it could be marked as accepted. +1 to the comment then.

Comment: Kongthap, glad I could help. @Stef K, did just that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited my answer after some reading in the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#virtualhost): Technically, you *can* state a domain in `VirtualHost`, but it [is discouraged](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/ip-based.html#single) because it can have [unexpected effects with DNS](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/dns-caveats.html). I assume that happened with your config.

---

In your Apache configuration you used the `VirtualHost` directive in a possibly problematic way. You stated the domain name in it, e. g. `<VirtualHost restaurant.local>`. But this is discouraged in favor of stating the servers IP address. The domain name(s) get defined inside the `VirtualHost` block, for example with `ServerName` or `ServerAlias`.

In the `VirtualHost` directive, you can state the IP address you want to your virtual host to listen at, plus the port:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
```

This virtual host definition only gets applied if a client (in most cases, a web browser) connects to IP 127.0.0.1 on port 80. Because 127.0.0.1 is (in almost every case) the internal loopback device, this virtual host can only be reached from the server itself. Of course, on public servers you would rather use a public IP address.

If you want to apply a virtual host definition to any IP (that reaches the server on the network level), you can use the `*` wildcard, for example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Comment: Can I use wild card such as 192.168.1.* to get response only from the clients in my LAN?

Comment: @Kongthap, according to the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#virtualhost) you can't. Full IP or `*` only (and `_default_` as kind of catchall). But I think you might be missinterpreting the directive: In `VirtualHost` you state the _server_ ip, not the _client_ ip. To restrict access to specific _client_ IPs, you might want to read up on directives like `allow`, `deny` and `order`, possibly in combination with `Directory` and/or `Location`.